# how to close the fileInputStream while reading the property file

Tags: java

I have following code :

```
    // Read properties file.
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     try {
     properties.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties"));
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     system.out.println("FileNotFound");
     }catch (IOException e) {
     system.out.println("IOEXCeption");
     }
```

Is it required to close the FileInputStream? If yes, how do I do that? I am getting a bad practice error in my code checklist . Asking it to put finally block.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You must the close the `FileInputStream`, as the `Properties` instance will not. From the `Properties.load()` javadoc:

> The specified stream remains open after this method returns.

Store the `FileInputStream` in a separate variable, declared outside of the `try` and add a `finally` block that closes the `FileInputStream` if it was opened:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream("filename.properties");
    properties.load(fis);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    system.out.println("FileNotFound");
} catch (IOException e) {
    system.out.println("IOEXCeption");
} finally {
    if (null != fis)
    {
        try
        {
            fis.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) since Java 7:

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
try (final FileInputStream fis =
         new FileInputStream("filename.properties"))
{
    properties.load(fis);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("FileNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOEXCeption: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should always close your streams, and doing it in the `finally` block is a good practice. The reason for this is that the `finally` block always gets executed, and you want to make sure that the stream is always closed, even if Something Bad happens.

```
    FileInputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        inStream = new FileInputStream("filename.properties");
        properties.load(inStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFound");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOEXCeption");
    } finally {
        try {
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you are using Java 7, this becomes much easier, since a new [`try-with`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) syntax was introduced. Then you can write like this:

```
try(FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("filename.properties")){
       properties.load(inStream);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFound");
   } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOEXCeption");
}
```

and the stream is closed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

here is an example:

```
    public class PropertiesHelper {
    public static Properties loadFromFile(String file) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            properties.load(stream);
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lombok @Cleanup to do it simply.
http://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
 try {
   @Cleanup FileInputStream myFis = new FileInputStream("filename.properties");
   properties.load(myFis);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   System.out.println("FileNotFound");
 }catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("IOEXCeption");
 }
```

Or, only if your are using Java 7, there is the "try with resource" new feature.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
 try (FileInputStream myFis = new FileInputStream("filename.properties")) {
   properties.load(myFis);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   System.out.println("FileNotFound");
 }catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("IOEXCeption");
 }
```